# Mousedown scroll function not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've got a button that is intended to scroll down a div when the mouse button is clicked and held on it . I thought this should work but it only scrolls one px per click as oppose to scrolling until the mouse up event .

code:

```
 var howfar = 0;
    $('#scrolldown').mousedown(function() {

        howfar ++;
        $('#scrollbox').scrollTop(howfar);

    });
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: May be there is not enough content to scroll. Did you notice that?

Comment: @Paul I'm trying to get the content of one div to scroll while the mouse is down on my button div .

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Yes there is defiantly enough content to scroll . If you read my post you'll see this isn't the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping `mousedown` continously doesn't mean it will fire that event continously, it will only fire once. What you can do it start increasing the scrollTop once `mousedown` event triggers using `setInterval` and then clear the interval on `mouseup` event.

Try something like this.

```
var howfar = 0;
var timer;
$('#scrolldown').mousedown(function() {
    var innerHeight = $('#scrollbox').css('height', 'auto').height();
    $('#scrollbox').css('height', '100px');
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(howfar < innerHeight){
            $('#scrollbox').scrollTop(howfar++);
        }
        else{//Clear the interval
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 10);
});
$('#scrolldown').mouseup(function() {
     clearInterval(timer);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWh5/)**

Comment: I do like that , I was going on long the same lines myself but thought there might be something simpler . Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var shouldScrool = false
    takeAction,
    count = 0;

takeAction = function() {
   count = 0;
   while(takeAction) {
        count++;
        $('#scrollbox').scrollTop(count);
   }
};
$('#scrolldown').mousedown(function() {
    takeAction = true;
    takeAction();
});

$('#scrolldown').mouseup(function() {
    takeAction = false;
});
```

Comment: I'm concerned that using a `while` loop here will cause everything to lock up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/)